# How to keep baseUrl when using uri() in spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Using `Spring Boot` 2.1.3.RELEASE: `WebClient` will stop using the provided `baseUrl` when passing an `URI` to `uri()` method. It will keep `baseUrl` when a string is passed to `uri()` though.

How can I provide a `baseUrl` and pass an `URI`?

```
public WebClient webClient() {
  return WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
    .build();
}
```

and

```
webClient.get().uri(URI.create("/foo/%23bar"))...
```

throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute:
```

and the request url becomes

```
request url: /foo/%23bar
```

Comment: I think this is a bug. It happens to `URI` and `String`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you pass new `URI` object, you override base `URI`.
You should use `uri` method with lambda as a parameter, like in example:

```java
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                                     .baseUrl("http://localhost")
                                     .build();

webClient.get()
         .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("api", "v2", "json", "test").build())
         .exchange();
```

Answer (score 10):

A slightly different way - use **path** instead of **pathSegment** on existing uri object. It helps to maintain the path conveniently in configuration/constant form.

```
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                                     .baseUrl("http://localhost")
                                     .build();

webClient.get()
         .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("api/v2/json/test").build())
         .exchange();
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you setup a `UriBuilderFactory` like you do by `baseUrl(String uri)` call, the simplest way to add the needed branch is to use
[uri(String uri,Object... uriVariables)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.UriSpec.html#uri-java.lang.String-java.util.function.Function-) signature, without specifying the second parameter given that's declared as varargs then can be 0 length.

In your case it simply reduces to:

```java
public WebClient webClient() {
  return WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl("https://example.com")
    .build();
}

webClient.get().uri("/foo/bar")
```

Comment: This actually solves the problem posted by OP. I don't want to use uriBuilder lambda as I have my URI provided from the caller. I'd rather like to use .uri( URI ) which sounds like it's more elegant but if the WebClient is broken I can go with .uri ( URI.toString() ). Thanks!